# Recursively check if a String is balanced

Tags: java, string, recursion

I want to check if a String has matching braces, brackets or parenthesis.

```
For example:
{}
()
[]
```

I can do it with a stack. I want to do it with recursion. I was reading the answers for a similar question and the replies were recursion mixed in with a stack. An user responded to those answers saying that recursion is also a stack so your recursive method should not have a stack in the parameters -- this makes sense to me.

I have a big problem though, I'm looking through the String backwards and always removing the last position I check until the String is empty so I return true. I can't picture how I will check for the particular parts, braces, brackets or parenthesis without having an extra parameter in my method to hold what I am looking for. Yet I keep thinking there has to be an easier way to do this.

```
public boolean isBalanced(String in)
{
    if(in.isEmpty())
        return true;

    if(in.charAt(in.length()) == '}')
    {
        return recIsBalanced(in.substring(0, in.length()));
    }

    else if(in.charAt(in.length()) == ']')
    {

    }


    return recIsBalanced(in.substring(0, in.length()));
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What benefit are you trying to gain from doing this recursively instead of iteratively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to solve this problem using recursion is to shrink the string from both directions. You iterate from left and from right until you see . If these do not match, String is not balanced otherwise apply same algorithm for the String enclosed between those braces. Going only from one end will be a lot trickier and you will have to store some state.

EDIT: thanks to DanielFischer. Actually iterate from one side e.g. left until you find a brace(if this brace is not opening one return `false`). Than iterate from the other side(in this case right) until you find a matching brace. Now the string will be balanced if and only if the substring enclosed within this braces is balanced **and** the string to the right of the closing bracket are both balanced using recursion.

Comment: In my understanding, `"()[]{}"` is balanced. Your test would say it isn't.

Comment: @DanielFischer Correct. I will fix that. Thank you.

Comment: EDIT: Very interesting. I just read your "EDIT". However, I think that solution would return that ([ )] as correct.

Comment: @CharlieK no I think you missunderstood me. You iterate from left and find a `(` and than iterate from right(same level of recursion no recursive call yet) and find `)`. **Then** you do a recursive calls for the substring between `(` and `)` and the section on the right of `)`.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev "( and than iterate from right(same level of recursion no recursive call yet) and find". So a loop inside the recursive call looking for a closing parenthesis?

Comment: @CharlieK yes that is my idea and I believe this is the only option to solve the problem without storing some kind of state between different levels of recursion

Comment: This method will fail on `"()()"` by returning "unbalanced" and `"([)]"` by returning "balanced".

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static boolean isBalanced(String str) {

    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (str.contains("()")) {
        return isBalanced(str.replaceFirst("\\(\\)", ""));
    }

    if (str.contains("[]")) {
        return isBalanced(str.replaceFirst("\\[\\]", ""));
    }

    if (str.contains("{}")) {
        return isBalanced(str.replaceFirst("\\{\\}", ""));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, not replacing anything, straight up recursion:

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public  boolean balance(String s, int start, int end)
{
   System.out.println("start:"+start + " end" + end);
   if (start == s.length()) return end == 0;
   if (end<0) return false;
   //if (end == s.length()-1) return start == 0;
   if (s.charAt(start) == '(')
     return balance(s, start+1, end+1);
   if (s.charAt(start) == ')')
     return balance(s, start+1, end-1);
   return balance(s, start+1, end );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by parsing input string. Grammar for this case is:

```
P -> (P)
P -> [P]
P -> {P}
P -> e  (Null)
```

It is easier to track position what is parsed in a string, and that recursion stack holds what parenthesis to be closed. Here is simple python implementation.

```
ps = { '{': '}', '(': ')', '[': ']'}
all_ps = set(['{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']'])
read_position = 0

def _is_balanced( s, closing_par=None ):
  global read_position
  while read_position < len(s):
    if s[read_position] == closing_par:
      read_position += 1         # Read closing parenthesis
      return True
    elif s[read_position] in ps:
      read_position += 1         # Read opening parenthesis
      if not _is_balanced( s, ps[s[read_position-1]] ):
        return False
    else:
      if s[read_position] not in all_ps:
        read_position += 1       # Read non-parenthesis char
      else:
        return False            # It is closing parenthesis, witouh opening before
  return closing_par is None    # Are we looking for a closing parenthesis?

def is_balanced( s ):
  global read_position
  read_position = 0  # Reset parsing position
  return _is_balanced( s )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isBalanced(String str)
{
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (str.charAt(0) == '(') {
        return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ')'
            && isBalanced(str.substring(1, str.length()));
    }
    else if (str.charAt(0) == '[') {
        return str.charAt(str.length() -  1) == ']'
            && isBalanced(str.substring(1, str.length()));
    }
    else if (str.charAt(0) == '{') {
        return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '}'
            && isBalanced(str.substring(1, str.length()));
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
```